# Connect from local machine to aws MSK

Tags: c#, .net, apache-kafka, aws-msk, sasl-scram

I followed "[public access](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/public-access.html)" to set up the configuration. I have two goals, Firstly, I want to create topic from local terminal by using this command line "[/bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --bootstrap-server ZookeeperConnectString --replication-factor 3 --partitions 1 --topic ExampleTopicName](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/msk-password.html)", but it always return "the broker is not available". Secondly, I want to connect MKS from local .Net Application. However, it seams cannot connect to the MKS successfully.

This is my some configuration that attach on my MKS

1. Create public subnet 172.31.0.0/20 and 172.31.16.0/20 and attach an Internet Gateway
2. Close unauthenticated access control off and turn on **SASL/SCRAM** access-control methods. Besides, I attached an secret for this authentication and add allow.everyone.if.no.acl.found to false to cluster's configuration.
3. Turn on public access
4. Cluster configuration
   [Cluster configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mJB1.png)
5. Producer Configuration
   [Producer Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OinNM.png)
6. Security Group
   [Security Group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ll4Yl.png)

Does anyone can give me some advice or hints? I do some research that not sure I have to add listeners in my cluster configuration? Thanks for your time and consideration.

Comment: 1) `kafka-topics.sh` should use `--bootstrap-server`, not `--zookeeper` since it is deprecated. Also, you need `--command-config` to pass a properties file with SASL details 2) I suggest you contact AWS Support if their own documentation is not  working

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thank you for point out should use "bootstrap server". I changed it and still not work. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was struggling with MSK, too. I finally got it working and maybe give some hints here:

- according to the docs at AWS, only SCRAM-SHA-512 is supported, not -256
- in the SG, I did add a rule for inbound traffic to accept from anywhere (0.0.0.0)

Hope that helps,

```
donbachi
```